# Adjusting to and back the size of images with javascript and Django query set

Tags: javascript, html, css, django-templates, django-queryset

My image model stores the dimension of the image:

```
class Image(Work):
    size_height_cm = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    size_width_cm = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    size_depth_cm = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My queryset search filters for Images in view.py:

```
works=Image.objects.filter(creator=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

I render the image on my page like this:

```
{% for work in works %}
<div class="work">
    <a href="../../work/{{ work.pk }}">
        <img class="work-object" src="{{ work.pic.url }}" alt="{{ work.name_complete }}" height="{{ work.display_height }}">
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

What I would like to do is to create two buttons: Button 1 and Button 2

When I click Button 1, it will resize all of the images to a height of 100px. like this:

```
{% for work in works %}
<div class="work">
    <a href="../../work/{{ work.pk }}">
        <img class="work-object" src="{{ work.pic.url }}" alt="{{ work.name_complete }}" height="100">
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I click on Button 2, I want to revert to my pre-stored image height.

How do I pass all of the height values with javascript when I'm iterating through the template?

Answer (score 1):

In your template, you can do something like this:

```
{% for work in works %}
<div class="work">
    <a href="../../work/{{ work.pk }}">
        <img 
            class="work-object" 
            src="{{ work.pic.url }}" 
            alt="{{ work.name_complete }}" 
            data-height="{{ work.display_height }}" 
            height="{{ work.display_height }}">
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<button class="one">Set image to 100px</button>
<button class="two">Set image to original size</button>
```

In JS:

```js
// Button One: Set all images height to 100px
document.querySelector("button.one").addEventListener("click", e =>{
  document.querySelectorAll(".work img").forEach( img => img.setAttribute("height","100px") );
})

// Button Two: Set all images height back to the original height
document.querySelector("button.two").addEventListener("click", e =>{
  document.querySelectorAll(".work img").forEach( img => img.setAttribute("height", img.getAttribute("data-height")) );
})
```

This is just a basic `PoC`. you can further optimize the JS code, by caching the element selectors and the value of the `data-height` attribute to avoid unnecessary calls to `querySelectorAll` and `getAttribute` (if the default height is the same for all images that is).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to do this.

### Create a CSS class that sets the height and add it with JS

```js
const myImgTag = document.getElementById('img-1');

document.getElementById('setHeightTo100px').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myImgTag.classList.add('img-h100');
})

document.getElementById('resetHeight').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myImgTag.classList.remove('img-h100');
})
```

```css
.img-h100 {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="setHeightTo100px">Set hight to 100px</button>
<button id="resetHeight">Reset height</button>

<img id="img-1" src="https://cataas.com/cat" height="400">
```

Of course, in your case, you would need to replace my `img-1` class name with something that has `{{ work.pk }}` (for example  `<img class="img-{{ work.pk }} sr=.."`) or any other identifier for your image.

---

### Save your original image height

You can use [Kostas's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423869/5078746) approach, and use `data-*` attributes for example to set the default height.

```js
const myImgTag = document.getElementById('img-1');

document.getElementById('setHeightTo100px').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myImgTag.setAttribute('height', '100px');
})

document.getElementById('resetHeight').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const originalHeight = myImgTag.getAttribute('data-original-height')
  myImgTag.setAttribute('height', originalHeight);

})
```

```html
<button id="setHeightTo100px">Set hight to 100px</button>
<button id="resetHeight">Reset height</button>

<img data-original-height="400px" id="img-1" src="https://cataas.com/cat" height="400">
```

And same, you can use your `work.pk` instead of the hardcoded value (`img-1`) I used in my example.

### Have a JS object where you store original heights before you resize

```js
const THE_SELECTED_ID = 'img-1'
const myImgTag = document.getElementById(THE_SELECTED_ID)

let imageHeights = {}

document.getElementById('setHeightTo100px').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // get image height
  const originalHeight = myImgTag.getAttribute('height')

  // save image id and height
  imageHeights = { ...imageHeights,
    [THE_SELECTED_ID]: originalHeight
  }
  myImgTag.setAttribute('height', '100px');
})

document.getElementById('resetHeight').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const originalHeight = imageHeights[THE_SELECTED_ID] || '100px'
  myImgTag.setAttribute('height', originalHeight);

})
```

```html
<button id="setHeightTo100px">Set hight to 100px</button>
<button id="resetHeight">Reset height</button>

<img id="img-1" src="https://cataas.com/cat" height="400">
```

---

If you go for any of the approaches above you have to adjust your template as I mentioned before:

```
{% for work in works %}
<div class="work">
    <a href="../../work/{{ work.pk }}">
        <img class="work-object image-{{ work.pk }}" src="{{ work.pic.url }}" alt="{{ work.name_complete }}" height="{{ work.display_height }}">
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And adjust the element selectors from `getElementById` to `querySelectorAll` in case you want to select all images on a page and apply the filter to them. Just note that `querySelectorAll` will return a list so you have to map or loop over it to perform your operations.